# How do I run specflow unit tests from a browser

Tags: bdd, specflow

I was able to run SpecFlow scenarios from a test project.  Now I would like to be able to run these scenarios from a browser.  How do I get that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to use something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Watin](http://watin.org/) to drive the browser from your SpecFlow step definitions.

Comment: I was on a team that managed to run it from a browser.  i don't know how they set it up, but it was useful because it let you run different subsets of tests by providing a tag - as in the tag you put above the scenario block